# Django RF, validation feedback methods.(return Response vs raise ValidationError)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I do validation in Django query set, the below code execute successfully and returns validation error if query fails to meet certain parameters

```
if second_condition:
    raise ValidationError("1 error")
else:
    serializer.save()
```

Meanwhile the below code fails to give response `1 error`  as expected.

```
if second_condition:
    return Response("1 error")
else:
    serializer.save()
```

Why is so ?

*note : avoid indentation format*

The complete code without formating given below

```
class CommentCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        request_user = self.request.user
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
        if Po.objects.filter(Q(user=request_user) & Q(item_id=pk) & Q(delivered=True)).exists():
            if Comment.objects.filter(Q(author=request_user) & Q(product=product)).exists():
                raise ValidationError("You have already commented")
            else:
                serializer.save(author=request_user, product=product)
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Purchase this item,prior to commenting")
```

Comment: These kinds of validations are supposed to be in your serializer class, not in view

Comment: Thanks, will using the validators in views cause any performance issue ?

Comment: Nop, But thats best practice

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to give response"? What is the response you observe on the frontend?

Comment: "fails to give response" = The backend accepts and saves the input values, then return the input values.

Comment: Your serializer does not have any data e.g `CommentSerializer(instance=comment, data=request.data)`. I assume ´serializer.save(author=request_user, product=product)´ won´t work [Validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)  [Saving](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)

Answer (score 1):

This is because *exceptions* bubble up the stack to the point where the exception gets caught by DRF and is handled as expected, while the *return* only returns the value from the *hook* perform_create. You can return Response-like instances from the main view handler (whatever that is in your django or DRF).
More on the hooks [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/), a didn't check what the return value means there.